# Why is my custom controller and visualforce page not outputting anything?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-controller

I am trying to create a simple VF page that is styled and has some info (name of two contacts related to the custom object, as well as the created date of the custom object).

As I don't want the viewer to have to be logged in, I am using a custom controller:

```
public class CertificateController {

    public External_Task__c externaltask { get; private set; }

    public CertificateController() {
        externaltask = [SELECT Id, Learner__c, Instructor__c, CreatedDate FROM External_Task__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

    public External_Task__c getExternalTask() {
        return externaltask;
    }
}
```

Here is the VF page code (pre-styling):

```
<apex:page controller="CertificateController">
    <apex:outputField value="{!externaltask.Learner__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!externaltask.Instructor__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!externaltask.CreatedDate}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!externaltask.Name}"/>
</apex:page>
```

But when I go to https://myvisualforcesitegoeshere.secure.force.com/certificate?id=a1T4W00000CnhsKUAR it gives me a blank page.

Also here is my config for that custom object: [image]

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

- multiple getters (two different syntaxes)
- querying into a single object instead of a list.

Remove the `public` attribute and the `{ get; private set; }` the variable and turn into a list of tasks:

```
public External_Task__c[] externaltasks { get; private set; }
```

Query to a list (more error tolerant):

```
externaltasks = [SELECT Id, Learner__c, Instructor__c, CreatedDate 
                FROM External_Task__c 
                WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

Change your getter to return the first element of the list:

```
public External_Task__c getExternalTask() {
    if ((externaltasks == null || externaltasks.isempty()){
      return new External_Task__c();
    }
    return externaltasks[0];
}
```